# Can't send request from app to web app

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have a 404 status error (page not found). I only want to send a request from my Android app to Mean.io web app through
the following url:

```
http://192.168.0.103:3000/auth/register
```

I have also tried:

```
http://10.0.2.2:3000/auth/register
```

I had already googled but both of the solutions above didn't worked for me. However the url: `http://192.168.0.103:3000/auth/register` does work
on my Chrome browser on my pc.

Here is the code:

```
public class AppConfig {

    // Server user register url
    //public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/auth/register";
    public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://192.168.0.103:3000/auth/register";
}
```

If you want to know where the variable `URL_REGISTER` gets used. It's getting used in the `registerUser()` method.

I'm posting the method through a link, because the method is too big to post it here. In the link below you can see that the `URL_REGISTER` gets used on line 10.

Link: http://pastebin.com/ttH6upnb

Comment: Maybe the server is not accessible from device, try doing that with a public IP or try the app in emulator in your machine

Comment: did you tried hitting that url from outside device like some HTTP client ? like Postman or browser ?

Comment: Did you try accessing this URL from your mobile chrome browser? from the same device you try to run your app from.

Comment: 404 means that you are reaching the server, and the server is returning the 404 error. Check your server logs to see what the problem is.

Comment: @Udi Idan It also works from my mobile browser.

Comment: @CommonsWare it comes indeed from the server. Here is a screenshot of the logs link: http://i.imgur.com/yAwGdL3.png   I'm still finding out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 be sure you connect to the server

192.168  and 10.0 are local addresses (not going to internet)

beware, if you get 404, perhaps another server like proxy responds to you

2 read this: [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

3 begin by getting page "/" and check the headers (good server, etc.)

4 then verify your code, step by step

5 check if GET or POST, and authentication is not easy (check the headers)